# jquery | on click action works only first time

Tags: jquery, click, action

Why script from URL used below works only when i click the element first time, and after second not?

```
<span id="hider">hide</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('span#hider').click(function() {
    if($('span#hider:contains("hide")')) {
        $('span#hider').html('show');
    }
    else if($('span#hider:contains("show")')) {
        $('span#hider').html('hide');
    }
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c40hjnpq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `jQuery()` constructor returns an object, which will always be true so your first `if` block is always executed

```
$('#hider').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':contains("hide")')) {
        $(this).html('show');
    } else if ($(this).is(':contains("show")')) {
        $(this).html('hide');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rc2docrb/)

---

But this can be simplified as

```
$('#hider').click(function () {
    $(this).html(function (i, html) {
        return $.trim(html) == 'hide' ? 'show' : 'hide';
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rc2docrb/2/)

Comment: WOW. Second solution is great :) Good job mate!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span#hider:contains("hide")')
```

This does not check whether or not the `#hider` contains the text 'hide', as it seem you think it does. What it does is make a list of all the `span#hider` elements that *do* contain that text. If none do, it returns a jQuery wrapper object.

Therefor, if you use `if( $('yourSelector') )` and nothing with your selector is found, it will always return truthy, so your code never gets into the second `if`.

Instead, you should do this:

```
$('span#hider').click(function() {
    if($('span#hider').html() == "hide") {
        $('span#hider').html('show');
    }
    else if($('span#hider').html() == "show") {
        $('span#hider').html('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You very much for detailed explanation! Now all is simple! Thank You one more time.

Comment: If this was the correct solution, please mark it as the accepted answer :) (the checkmark below the post score)

Answer (score 1):

Just make it simple mate:

```
$('#hider').click(function() {
    var newValue =  $('#hider').html() === 'show'   ? "hide": "show";
    $('#hider').html(newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('span#hider').click(function() {
    if($('span#hider').text()=='hide') {
        alert($('span#hider').text());
        $('span#hider').html('show');
    }
    else if($('span#hider').text()=='show') {
        alert($('span#hider').text());
        $('span#hider').html('hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hider').bind('click',function(){
    var hider = $(this);
    var hiderval = $(this).html();
    if(hiderval.indexOf("show") > -1){
        $(this).html('hide');
    }
    else if(hiderval.indexOf("hide") > -1){
        $(this).html('show');
    }
});
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/c40hjnpq/23/